# Como deletar arquivos de uma data específica no linux

Tags: linux

Dentro de uma pasta eu tenho arquivos de 2006 até 2018

e quero deletar somente os arquivos do ano de 2017

como fazer isso no linux?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302011/finding-and-deleting-files-with-a-specific-date

Comment: Você pode tentar da seguinte forma:
find . -ctime -365 | xargs rm

Explicando o comando acima, o find é para procurar arquivos e diretórios no Linux o . indica o diretório que você está (não faça isso dentro de um diretório que você não quer apagar os arquivos) , -ctime procura arquivos pela data de criação, -365 indica o tempo que você está procurando, | xargs esse comando pega a saída do comando find e aplica a outra ação solicitada no caso o rm.